# Pending open lightning channel

Tags: lightning-network, ln-opening-channels, bumpfee

I opened a lightning channel with RTL on my raspiblitz. It took too low fees by default (my fault).
So I tried in RTL to pump the TX but this doesn't help. It seems that there was an second TX created through 'CPFP'. Pumping the fees again doesn't change anything.

Main TX: https://mempool.space/de/tx/740f89e808a8beb7fe116ed3d151f6373087b5f6ccb86ac976c777dd26928ad7
Pumped TX:
https://mempool.space/de/tx/19c7b5498f0a1228478abaa902735e947c3812a9dc574b5c10d83dfcf9bb7999

I also tried to pump the fees with Zeus, but there I get an error message:

[image]

The pending is now for over 4 weeks and the sats are stucked.
As I understand I have to pump also the parent TX, but how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to spend parent:1, but this is spent by `19c7b5498f0a1228478abaa902735e947c3812a9dc574b5c10d83dfcf9bb7999`. So you'll need to either RBF the child, or make a grandchild.

Comment: @DavidsonSouza Will the TX ever abort or will my Sats be locked forever?

Comment: Looks like they got confirmed in block 810120? Is your problem solved?

Comment: @DavidsonSouza Yeah I got it finally solved by bumping the fee with zeus. Thanks